# Predecessor in graphs?

Tags: graph

Does the term "predecessor" of a node mean the node that IMMEDIATELY precedes that node ( i.e. is parent of the node) or does it refer to a node at a distance k above that node where k>=1.

Comment: The term would depend on the context of the problem instance (statement). Say for example if you are talking about the doing a BFS on the graph, the predecessor or parent would mean the node that discovers that particular node. Please give us more context here for better answers.

Comment: Hi, I came across the term while reading about BFS. What are the other meanings apart from being parent in BFS.

Answer (score 7):

From wikipedia:

> If v is reachable from u, then u is a
>   predecessor of v and v is a successor
>   of u. If there is an arc from u to v,
>   then u is a direct predecessor of v,
>   and v is a direct successor of u.

Comment: The symmetry of definitions between successor and predecessor.